# Get CAPTCHA url from html code using python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

I need to get the CAPTCHA url from this [web page](http://www.nimbuzzout.com/en/register):

This is part of html code from above website which is has the capatcha url:

```
<span id="recaptcha_image"></span></p><p><label></label><span>
<a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload ();" id="recaptcha_reload_btn"></a>
</span></p>
```

but i can't do that because the CAPTCHA url looks like javascript code

```
javascript:Recaptcha.reload ();
```

so how i can get the url using python.?
I hope someone help me.

Thank you

Comment: The image is loaded with JavaScript after the page loads to stop it being scraped. You'll need to do more than parse the HTML. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can use some kind of web driver instrumentation tool to push the captcha button, and then capture the created html. In python you can use [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) built above the selenium "raw" webdriver, with a nice and pythonic api, although there are many more similiar options.

But I'm afraid you are missing something basic here. the captch doesn't really have a "url" . the "url" is used (probably in an anchor element) to trigger js code, that would create the actual captcha html (probably with no link inside, but with an image). If this is what you are after, then the method I mentioned above would help you. If not.. then I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

**UPDATE**

There isn't really a "captcha url" so this is a wild goose chase.. the captcha is an image(in this specific webpage). the url you are referring to is the one to regenerate the captcha and isn't really a url, but a way to trigger a pre coded js function.

If you are trying to click it, in order to regenerate the image, then the way above is the way to go, if what you mean is getting the image `src`. then again, you'll have to generate the image and then get the html and parse it for the src.

Good luck

Comment: I try alot to coded something to do what i want but all what i coded it's dosn't work because the javascript code so i ask here to find some help about that. But can i save the picture in folder from the webpage using python?

Comment: `import bs4
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.nimbuzzout.com/en/register')

data = (response.content)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
link = soup.select('span.recaptcha_image a[href^]')

print link`

Comment: And you are trying to get the image?

Comment: No, i try to get the capatcha url